# UV absorption decrease with an increase in concentration

Tags: visible-light, photons, spectroscopy, wavelength

I am working on a project measuring the absorbance of a solution which contains surfactant and hard brine. The solution has a constant concentration of surfactant and varying concentration of hard brine.

I measured the absorbance of the solution in order to create a calibration curve. The problem I am facing is that it goes against Beer-Lambert's law and shows a negative trend.

The solution is cloudy and I had to dilute in order to get an absorbance below 1. Is it possible to have lower absorbance with an increase in concentration? I have yet to find an example of this story of behaviour anywhere.

Comment: Could you please clarify your experiment? What absorbs UV - the surfactant or hard brine? (what is hard brine, by the way?) How do you create the calibration curve - do you change concentration of one or both ingredients, is the dilution factor constant?

Comment: I'm investigating the effect of salinity and composition on adsorption of surfactants by a rock sample.Hard brine has magnesium and calcium in it. The calibration curve will have adsorbance on y axis and concentration on X axis. I change the concentration of one and keep the other constant and then vice versa. The calibration curve for constant brine came out a straight line. The curve for constant surfactant came out with a negative trend gradient. Dilution factors is constant yes

Comment: Optical absorbtion should definitely increase with concentration. Could you provide some values for two different concentrations? Also, how do you change the concentration of hard brine for calibration?